# What code exactly must be put on the main thread in iOS?

Tags: ios, multithreading, performance, user-interface, grand-central-dispatch

Could somebody please explain to me which lines of code in particular should go on the main thread in iOS?

I have something like the following:

```
- (void)asyncWorkOnLayingOutSKUs:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture andBlock:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {
__block NSTimeInterval totalTi = -[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
//
dispatch_queue_t callerQ = dispatch_get_current_queue();
dispatch_queue_t loadingQ = dispatch_queue_create("ff.aq", NULL);
dispatch_async(loadingQ, ^{

    //Code below can be placed here and then I used: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //code here that must go on main thread });  in order to make it work

    BOOL trueBool = YES;
    //
    dispatch_async(callerQ, ^{
        totalTi += [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        NSLog(@"Performance: %g sec", totalTi);
        completion(trueBool);
        if(completion){

    //For now, there is no multithreading since all code is placed on main thread...

            self.timingDate = [NSDate date];

            switch (self.lastButtonPressedForDragTags) {
                case 1:{
                    self.slotOneButtonIndex = gesture.view.tag-1;
                } break;
                case 2:{
                    self.slotTwoButtonIndex = gesture.view.tag-1;
                } break;
                case 3:{
                    self.slotThreeButtonIndex = gesture.view.tag-1;
                } break;
                case 4:{
                    self.slotFourButtonIndex = gesture.view.tag-1;
                } break;
                case 5:{
                    self.slotFiveButtonIndex = gesture.view.tag-1;
                } break;
            }

            int touchedtag = gesture.view.tag;
            UIView* thisView;
            UIScrollView* thisScrollView;

            switch (gesture.view.superview.superview.tag) {
                case -1:{
                    thisView = self.dragTagsScrollViewContainer;
                    thisScrollView = self.dragTagsScrollView;
                } break;
                case -2:{
                    thisView = self.SKUTagsScrollViewContainer;
                    thisScrollView = self.SKUTagsScrollView;
                } break;
                case -3:{
                    thisView = self.otherTagsScrollViewContainer;
                    thisScrollView = self.otherTagsScrollView;
                } break;
                case -4:{
                    thisView = self.leftDraggedTagsScrollViewContainer;
                    thisScrollView = self.leftDraggedTagsScrollView;
                } break;
            }

            UIButton *button = (UIButton*)[thisView viewWithTag:touchedtag];

            if(![button isSelected]){
                [self setButtonSelected:button];
            }
            else{
                [self setButtonDeselected:button];
            }

            //Get the position of the button RELATIVE to the superview by subtracting the content offset for x direction:
            CGRect buttonPosition = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x - thisScrollView.contentOffset.x, button.frame.origin.y, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);

            CGRect sizeOfScrollView = CGRectMake(0, 0, thisScrollView.frame.size.width, thisScrollView.frame.size.height);

            if(CGRectContainsRect(sizeOfScrollView, buttonPosition)){}
            else{
                //extend scrollview to L or R
                CGPoint rightBottomEdgeOfButton = CGPointMake(buttonPosition.origin.x + buttonPosition.size.width, buttonPosition.origin.y + buttonPosition.size.height);
                CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(sizeOfScrollView, buttonPosition);
                float amountToMove;
                float currentXDirectionOffset = thisScrollView.contentOffset.x;
                CGPoint newOffset;

                if (CGRectContainsPoint(sizeOfScrollView, rightBottomEdgeOfButton)){
                    //Need to move Left
                    amountToMove = button.frame.size.width - intersection.size.width + 5;
                }
                else{
                    //Need to move Right
                    amountToMove = -(button.frame.size.width - intersection.size.width + 5);
                }
                newOffset = CGPointMake(currentXDirectionOffset-amountToMove, thisScrollView.contentOffset.y);

                [thisScrollView setContentOffset:newOffset];
            }

            [self.SKUTagsScrollViewContainer removeFromSuperview];

            NSMutableArray* arrayToUse = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self getIntersectionArray]];


            [self populateScrollViewWithArray:arrayToUse andScrollView:self.SKUTagsScrollView withContainer:self.SKUTagsScrollViewContainer andmaxNumberOfRowsForScrollView:6];

#ifdef DEBUG
            NSLog(@"Time taken to AFTER populateScrollViewWithArray: %g and for %d controls", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.timingDate], [arrayToUse count]);
#endif
        }
    });
});
dispatch_release(loadingQ);
}
```

Right now obviously nothing is on the loading q and the method `populateScrollViewWithArray` basically arranges some buttons on a UIScrollView.  I found I was able to 'wrap' any code I thought was vital to the ui rendering within `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` and I could then place all of the code shown here within `if(completion){}` on the loading q.

Both options worked and I measured performance and found I got similar results.

My problems are that I am new to iOS and I would like to know:

How can I maximise performance using threads?

What exactly should go onto the main thread?  In the method `populateScrollViewWithArray` I did the following:

```
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [scrollview addSubview:scrollViewContainer];
            [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
        });
```

But I did things like create labels, create buttons and add gestures on the loading q (didn't explicitly surround them within `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});`

Could anyone point me to a concise explanation other than 'read the documentation' as I usually find the Apple docs quite long winded.  A bit like this question.....

Comment: Thanks.  Short answer to a long question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that most UIKit classes are unsafe to use from a background thread unless the documentation explicitly says otherwise (and sometimes the documentation is inconsistent, and sometimes it breaks, e.g. UIKit drawing is supposed to be thread-safe since 4.0 but was broken in iOS 5.x).

IIRC the docs also suggest that *creating* views on a background thread (e.g. by loading a nib) is safe provided they haven't been added to a window. I haven't soak-tested this, though, so there are probably some edge-cases which aren't safe (UIWebView is probably one of them).

It's also *slightly* more complicated than that, since some UIKit classes are unsafe to *release* from a background thread according to the [GKTapper example code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Listings/Classes_GameCenterManager_m.html):

> If a view controller is **referenced** in a block that executes on a secondary queue,
>   that view controller may be released (and dealloc'd) outside the main queue.  **This is true even if the actual block is scheduled on the main thread.**  ... UIKit view controllers should only be accessed on the main thread, so the snippet above may lead to **subtle and hard to trace bugs**.

Your code captures `self` and `gesture` in a (block referenced by a) block that runs on a background thread, which means they might be released on a background thread, which might occasionally crash.

Other nitpicks:

- `totalTi` doesn't need to be a `__block` variable.
- `loadingQ` should be replaced with a global queue.
- `if(completion)` is always true (`completion(trueBool)` in the line above which crashes if `completion` is NULL).
- You could move the bulk of the code to a completion method in the VC instead of having 6 levels of indentation.